# I'm facing a problem in a listening comprehension. "how we might wean ourselves off our chosen (or shows an?) addictive pursuit."?

Tags: meaning

I can't actually understand this part. [03:15s](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=f55QO2isoKM)

> We could start a think too (or *We could start a think to* *OR We could start to think too*?) at (or *that*?) how we might wean ourselves off our chosen (or *shows an*?) addictive pursuit.

I can't understand this, what does the lecturer mean by "our chosen addictive *pursuit*"?

We should wean ourselves off (=gradually stop doing) what?

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of *pursuit*?

Comment: The text is provided as subtitles to the youtube video - and is correct.  No need to guess at what the actual words are.  'We could start to think, too, of how we might wean ourselves off our chosen addictive pursuit."

Answer (score 3):

One meaning of "pursuit" is "an activity that you do as a hobby". It is often qualified with an adjective (or adjectival noun). For example "leisure pursuits"=things we do to relax, "Country pursuits"=activities like horseriding, hunting or hiking.

Here the speaker talks about "addictive pursuits"=any activity that might become addictive, such as gambling, video games or social media. "Our chosen addictive pursuit" because at some point we must have chosen to start gambling, or playing video games, before it became addictive.

To "wean oneself off something" means to gradually reduce the amount of something. Originally "to wean" is the reduce the amount of milk a baby has, replacing it with solid food.

So the speaker means "How we might reduce the amount of time we spend on the activity that we are addicted to.